# Rails: Nested form_for Errors: 'ActionController::UrlGenerationError'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, nested-form-for

I am having trouble using the form_for correctly for my nested resources.

I have the following set up in my models:

**team.rb**

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :superheroes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :superheroes
end
```

**superhero.rb**

```
class Superhero < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
end
```

My routes: **routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'teams#index'

  resources :teams do
    resources :superheroes
  end

  get '/teams/:team_id/superheroes/:id', to: 'superheroes#show', as: 'team_superheros'

end
```

In **'/app/views/superheroes/new.html.erb'**

```
<%= form_for [@team, @superhero] do |f| %>
  <p>Name</p>
  <p><%= f.text_field :name %></p>
  <p>True Identity</p>
  <p><%= f.text_field :true_identity %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit 'SAVE' %></p>
<% end %>
```

Lastly, in **superheroes_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @team = Team.find_by_id(params[:team_id])
  @superhero = @team.superheroes.build
end
```

I think maybe my understanding of the nested form_for isn't correct. When I navigate to the new_superhero page I originally got the following error:

```
undefined method `team_superheros_path'
```

So I added the following redirection route to **routes.rb**:

```
get '/teams/:team_id/superheroes/:id', to: 'superheroes#show', as: 'team_superheros'
```

This leaves me with the "Errors: 'ActionController::UrlGenerationError'" message with the specific error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"superheroes", :team_id=>#<Team id: 1, name: "Watchmen", publisher: "DC", created_at: "2016-10-22 04:04:46", updated_at: "2016-10-22 04:04:46">} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I must just be using the form_for incorrectly. I can create superheroes in the console via: watchmen.superheroes.create(name:"The Comedian",true_identity:"Edward Blake") and when the page is generated my @superhero is a blank instance of that class.

Any help?

Comment: I think the problem lies in routes.rb can you post your complete routes.rb?

Comment: Edited original post to reflect whole routes.db file. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** It turned out to be an irregular plural situation. I updated the code below to show what worked overall.

My routes: **routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'teams#index'

  resources :teams do
    resources :superheroes
  end

end
```

In **'/app/views/superheroes/new.html.erb'**

```
<%= form_for [@team,@superhero] do |f| %>
  <p>Name</p>
  <p><%= f.text_field :name %></p>
  <p>True Identity</p>
  <p><%= f.text_field :true_identity %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit 'SAVE' %></p>
<% end %>
```

In **superheroes_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @superhero = @team.superheroes.build
end
```

Turns out what I needed to do was create a migration to rename :superheros to :superheroes

```
class RenameTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    rename_table :superheros, :superheroes
  end
end
```

And then add to **inflections.rb**:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'superhero', 'superheroes'
end
```

That was doozy.